# PHP как защитить исходники от копирования и переноса

Tags: php

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите, как защитить исходный код от копирования? 
цель встроить проверку, например, домена/ip/лицензии, чтобы не скопировать проект на другой сервер...
Есть ли способ преобразовать php 7.2 в какой то  нечитаемый байт код. Но чтобы он также просто запускался? 
обфусцировать его до неузнаваемости. ну и чтобы не так легко снималась защита?

Сначала думал идти по пути eval() и там куча зашифрованных строк...
Но решил спросить, может есть что-то более интересное и свежее? и желательно бесплатное решение.

Comment: ioncube - https://www.ioncube.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть множество решений - ioncube и прочие. Бесплатных совсем стоящих не видел.
Сам пользую http://www.phplockit.com/ (Есть 30-ти дневный тест-период). Насчет 7.2 - попробуйте, не думаю, что должны быть проблемы.

Оптимально обфусцировать только ядро и ключевые модули.

Что еще хорошо в этой проге - во множестве настроек есть очень удобные функции привязки к домену, к ограничению по времени - очень удобно для демо - можно отдавать полноразмерный код для тестирования да и другие настройки тоже очень даже полезны.

Пример:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>
```

Обработанное:

```
<?php /* Это демо от Coder */$OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0'].=$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']{7}.$OOO000000{5};$GLOBALS['OOO000O00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$GLOBALS['O0O000O00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$GLOBALS['O0O000O00']=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$GLOBALS['O0O00OO00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$GLOBALS['OOO00000O']=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x20;eval($GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwTzAwJ10oJE9PTzBPME8wMCwncmInKTskR0xPQkFMU1snTzBPMDBPTzAwJ10oJE8wMDBPME8wMCwweDUxMSk7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwME8wJ10oJEdMT0JBTFNbJ09PTzAwMDAwTyddKCRHTE9CQUxTWydPME8wME9PMDAnXSgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4MWE4KSwnRW50ZXJ5b3V3a2hSSFlLTldPVVRBYUJiQ2NEZEZmR2dJaUpqTGxNbVBwUXFTc1Z2WHhaejAxMjM0NTY3ODkrLz0nLCdBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvJykpO2V2YWwoJE9PMDBPMDBPMCk7'));return;?>~Dkr9NHenNHenNHe1zfukgFMaXdoyjcUImb19oUAxyb18mRtwmwJ4LT09NHr8XTzEXRJwmwJXLO0xNWLyHA1SmT09NHeEXHr8Xk10PkrfHT0knTyYdk09NTzEXHeEXTZffhtOuTr9tWAxTBZfNHr8XHr9NHeEmbUILTzEXHr8XTzEXRtONTzEXTzEXHeEpRtfydmOlFmlvfbfqDykwBAsKa09aaryiWMkeC0OLOMcuc0lpUMpHdr1sAunOFaYzamcCGyp6HerZHzW1YjF4KUSvNUFSk0ytW0OyOLfwUApRTr1KT1nOAlYAaacbBylDCBkjcoaMc2ipDMsSdB5vFuyZF3O1fmf4GbPXHTwzYeA2YzI5hZ8mhULpK2cjdo9zcUILTzEXHr8XTzEXhTslfMyShtONTzEXTzEXTzEpKX==woajDo8Ik0ildoxvRtnbd3kSctrmKX==alVnRPIq
```

Comment: и каковы потери производительности при этом?

Comment: маленькая строчка в такую штуку не читаемую длинную преобразовалась?

Comment: @teran - Практически никаких - это я сейчас почти все возможные опции включил в проге. При обфускации только критического вообще незаметно. Но, при желании, каждый может тест провести и посмотреть сам - только нужно помнить, что чтоб рыбку съесть, нужно немного чем-то пожертвовать. Выбор за каждым)

Comment: тоесть скачать прогу и юзать как демку? 30 дней можно?

Comment: Да, конечно. Ну, и при желании ко мне обратитесь, дополнительно подскажу немного.

Comment: скачал, тестирую, пробую зашифровать модуль ядра. отключил обфускатор, иначе нельзя из других модулей обращаться. модуль написан на php7 c нейспейсами, все норм схавало и работает.
ну и имеем потерю в скорости загрузки порядка 1 милисекунды. 
было include core 0.04 ms стало  1.16 ms
ну  потери есть конечно, ну я думаю если шифровать только ключевое то можно

Comment: хотя когда как от 0.5 до 4 ms занимает загрузка этого файла

Comment: Такое не критично - если только нужное. Ну, не подойдет, то можно поискать что более подходящее - только этот ничего не требует дополнительного, а монстры шифрования требуют дополнений в серверной части и прочее. Ну, в общем - что мог, то сказал)

Comment: пасиб. думаю пойдет

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!

Comment: еще есть вопрос, я шифрую код, т.к. это наша собственность, начальство велело, но клиент говорит нельзя шифровать вдруг у вас там шеллы... есть ли какой то компромис? чтобы они как то этот код безопасно запускали, а мы остались с закрытым кодом?

Comment: Да нет компромиса - тут слова Ваше(компании), что там все чисто и прогнать код через он-лайн антивирусники, чтоб показать и эту сторону. А шеллы - ну, многие серьезные платформы идут с шифрованием ядра и многого другого - и никто не возмущается - так что, если они вам не верят, то тогда либо вы открываете им код, либо не работаете с ними. Да и встречный вопрос - а если они используют код без спроса не по назначению? - Если они сумеют ответить, тогда и Вы подумаете. А то односторонне получается. А доверие должно быть. А если врач не вколет положенного? А если состав колбасы другой? И тд.

Comment: Можно подписать официальный меморандум компаниями, что в предоставленном коде все чисто и содержится только заявленное.